# Using basename(__FILE__) to determine the page's name to change the title doesn't work

Tags: php, html, variables, if-statement

It is pretty simple, but I think I'm missing something crucial here:

```
<?php 
        $title = " | Unlimited Motors";
if (basename(__FILE__) == "index.php") {
    global $title;
    $title = "Home"." | Unlimited Motors";
}
if (basename(__FILE__) == "contact.php") {
    global $title;
    $title = "Contact Us"." | Unlimited Motors";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
```

You'd think something so simple would work.
Alas, it doesn't. The `echo $title;` part inside the `<title></title>` doesn't pick up the changed variable. It simple displays " | Unlimited Motors" as it was without the `if ()` changing it.
I'm a little confused at these global variables and stuff, so can anyone explain the error in here?

**Update:** It seems I forgot to add a few things I deemed unimportant:
**1)** Yes, I have already tested `basename(__FILE__)` in the main body and got "index.php".
**2)** Yes, I am using this in a header file, which is then `included` in other files.

Comment: `var_dump(basename(__FILE__));`

Comment: @u_mulder Hm? What do you mean? Should I add this `var_dump()` before `basename()`?

Comment: I mean you should test `basename(__FILE__)` contents.

Comment: just echo __ FILE __ to check whether it echoed something.

Comment: Maybe you should not base this on file names to begin with – but look at what URL was requested by the client. Yes, there _can_ be a direct correlation between URLs and file names, but there doesn’t have to be. Do a `var_dump($_SERVER);`, and then look for values that might be appropriate for this purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're using this code inside an `include`. According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php), `__FILE__` returns

> The full path and filename of the file with symlinks resolved. **If used inside an include, the name of the included file is returned.**

Comment: I see. That must be it. How do you think it should be resolved if I am to include the header file inside multiple other pages?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is best practice, but you could define a `$title` variable on top of each page, and call `include` immediately thereafter. Includes don't need to be at the top of the page.